Upper band for sizeof (struct foo)
How might one compute an upper band for the size of a given struct type? I believe the task can be reduced to finding an upper band for the amount of padding.
I am using "band," not "bound," because I understand that a definite upper limit may not be computable. I want to be very confident that attempting to compute the size of my structs (by the compiler) results in well-defined behavior and not an "exceptional condition." "Very" as in I would be willing to bet some lost productivity, but not anyone's life.
In part, what I want to know is: supposing that the compiler computes sizeof (struct foo), is that number of characters sufficient to store an object of type struct foo? Maybe not, if the attempt to compute sizeof (struct foo) results in an "exceptional condition?"
Related question

A compiler can choose to make any struct as large as it wants. It can add any arbitrary amount of tail padding.

In practice of course you know which ABI the compiler follows and that will specify the size exactly for each struct and of course no reasonable ABI will add padding for no reason.

So what exactly are you asking for?

What actual use case are you worried about? Is this for some extremely memory-constrained embedded system or something? Are you worried about compiling adversarial code written specifically to crash your compiler?

Are you trying to figure out what the size of a structure might be if you construct it without any regard to the alignment requirements of its members? So you want a function whose input is a list of member types and whose output is what the largest size of a structure containing just those member types will be, perhaps supposing the compiler inserts only padding needed for alignment? If so, do you have any information about the alignment requirements of the members? You will need at least some information to construct a bound.

So, is your question effectively, given a list of member alignment requirements and sizes, what is the worst order to put them in?

@EricPostpischil IMO it is XY problem.

If you want to make sure that the size of your struct does not go beyond what you expect, then you can write something like static_assert( sizeof(struct mystruct) <= 20 );. That way, your code will refuse to compile on platforms on which the struct would be too large.

@AndreasWenzel: That will not work in the circumstances their prior question indicates they anticipate.

If your concern is that the struct could be so large that its size is not representble by the data type size_t, then I believe you can rely on the compiler warning you that the object size is too large, even if the ISO C standard does not require this. If you want to be extra careful, you can check the result of the sizeof operator for plausibility, to ensure that a wraparound did not occur.

@EricPostpischil , I am not familiar with XY problem. Could you provide a reference?

@EricPostpischil Re "worst order:" I will choose an arbitrary ordering of struct members. Ideally, the ordering of members aligns with the concept being modeled. For example, by convention, we would have struct point { int x; int y; }; not struct point { int y; int x; };.

@AnaNimbus: I was not the person who wrote about an XY problem, but that is when a person has a problem Y, thinks of a solution X, and then has trouble with X and asks for help with X, when it may be easier to solve Y a different way.  In any case, you have not described the problem clearly enough for people to understand the problem. Rearranging int d and int y in a structure does nothing to affect the size. Update the question with examples and clear explanations.

@user2357112 Re "memory-constrained:" memory is always constrained: it is finite. A desktop machine might have 64 GiB RAM, but each application wants 4 GiB or more, so you can run a whopping 16 aps simultaneously. Would the answer to my question be different if SIZE_MAX were 65535 vs. ULLONG_MAX?

@AnaNimbus: Memory is finite, sure, but if a program is trying to use a struct so big its size doesn't fit in size_t, it's going to run into far more problems than just the problem you're looking at. This is a very weird issue to focus on.

@AnaNimbus, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem (and subsequent references made to it within that article)

Your latest edit is answered in your previous question, and it does not clarify the problem asked  about in this question. It is not even clear whether you are asking about some way in source code to detect at compile time, or at execution time, whether some structure definition is problematic (e.g., something one could write in C source code that would cause a diagnostic message) or are asking how a human looking at source code might determine whether there is or is not an issue with a structure’s size…

… You have also not said why there might be any fluctuation in a structure’s size. Given any particular ordinary C implementation and any particular ordered list of member types, the structure size is fully determined by the algorithm described here, absent compounding factors. So why is there any question about what the size would be? Is the member order not determined? Is the C implementation not determined?
